# LATEX ERROR: BAD MATH ENVIRONMENT DELIMITER. (all caps)

Tags: environments, delimiters

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, twoside, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{notes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{MATH 3142 Notes | Spring 2016}
\date{Updated: \today}
\author{Your Name Here\\ UNC Charlotte}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\setcounter{chapter}{9}
\chapter{The Euclidean Space \texorpdfstring{\(\mathbb R^n\)}{Rn}}


\section{The Linear Structure of \texorpdfstring{\(\mathbb R^n\)}{Rn}
and the Scalar Product}

\begin{proposition}[10.2]
  Let \(\mathbf u,\mathbf v,\mathbf w\in\mathbb R^n\)
  and \(\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R\). Then both of the following hold:
  \[
    \langle \mathbf u,\mathbf v\rangle=\langle \mathbf v,\mathbf u\rangle
  \]
  \[
    \langle \alpha\mathbf u+\beta\mathbf w,v\rangle
      =
    \alpha\langle \mathbf u,\mathbf v\rangle+\beta\langle \mathbf w,\mathbf v\rangle
  \]
\end{proposition}
\begin{proof}

\end{proof}

\begin{lemma}[10.4]
  For \(\mathbf u,\mathbf v\in\mathbb R^n\), \(\mathbf u,\mathbf v\) are
  orthogonal if and only if
  \(\|\mathbf u+\mathbf v\|=\|\mathbf u\|^2+\|\mathbf v\|^2\).
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}

\end{proof}

\begin{lemma}[10.5]
  For \(\mathbf u,\mathbf v\in\mathbb R^n\) where \(\mathbf v\not=\mathbf 0\),
  define \(\lambda=\frac{\langle \mathbf u,\mathbf v\rangle}{\langle \mathbf v,\mathbf v\rangle}\)
  and \(\mathbf w=\mathbf u-\lambda\mathbf v\). Then \(\mathbf v,\mathbf w\)
  are orthogonal and \(\mathbf u=\mathbf w+\lambda\mathbf v\).
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}

\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}[10.6, The Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality]
  For any two vectors \(\mathbf u,\mathbf v\in\mathbb R^n\),
  \[
    |\langle \mathbf u,\mathbf v\rangle|
      \leq
    \|\mathbf u\|\|\mathbf v\|
  .\]
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}

\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}[10.7, The Triangle Inequality]
  For any two vectors \(\mathbf u,\mathbf v\in\mathbb R^n\),
  \[
    \|\mathbf u+\mathbf v\|
      \leq
    \|\mathbf u\|+\|\mathbf v\|
  .\]
\end{theorem}

\begin{exercise}[3]
  Show that for \(\mathbf u\in\mathbb R^n\), \(\alpha\in\mathbb R\):
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item \(\|\mathbf u\|=0\) if and only if \(\mathbf u=\mathbf 0\).
    \item \(\|\alpha\mathbf u\|=|\alpha|\|\mathbf u\|\).
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
\begin{proof}

\end{proof}

\begin{exercise}[4]
  For \(\mathbf u,\mathbf v\in\mathbb R^n\) verify the identity
  \[
    \|\mathbf u-\mathbf v\|^2
      =
    \|\mathbf u\|^2+\|\mathbf v\|^2-2\langle \mathbf u,\mathbf v\rangle
  .\]
\end{exercise}
\begin{proof}

\end{proof}

\begin{exercise}[9]
  Let \(\mathbf u\in\mathbb R^n\) and suppose \(\|\mathbf u\|<1\).
  Show that for \(\mathbf v\in\mathbb R^n\),
  \(\|\mathbf v-\mathbf u\|<1-\|\mathbf u\|\) implies
  \(\|\mathbf v\|<1\).
\end{exercise}
\begin{proof}

\end{proof}

\begin{exercise}[10]
  Let \(\mathbf u\in\mathbb R^n\) and \(r>0\). Suppose \(\mathbf v,\mathbf w\in\mathbb R^n\)
  are at a distance less than \(r\) from \(\mathbf u\). Prove that if
  \(0\leq t\leq 1\), then the point \(t\mathbf v+(1-t)]\mathbf w\) is also
  at a distance less than \(r\) from \(\mathbf u\).
\end{exercise}
\begin{proof}

\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

The above markup is causing the strange error from the title: `LATEX ERROR: BAD MATH ENVIRONMENT DELIMITER.`

```
Errors:

./foo.tex:121: LATEX ERROR: BAD MATH ENVIRONMENT DELIMITER. [\end{document}]
./foo.tex:121: Extra }, or forgotten $. [\end{document}]
./foo.tex:121: Extra }, or forgotten $. [\end{document}]
./foo.tex:121: Missing $ inserted. [\end{document}]
./foo.tex:121: Missing } inserted. [\end{document}]
./foo.tex:121: Missing } inserted. [\end{document}]
```

Note that it's completely capitalized, unlike the error that I can get by adding an extra `$` in the document. Actually, adding any sort of environment seems to be causing the error. To make matters more bizarre, this error does not seem to occur when compiling on, say, Overleaf.

Since it's system-specific I'm not sure a solution will be found. For what it's worth I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. At the least, does anyone know why I'm getting the error in all uppercase?

Comment: I downloaded `notes.tex` and `notes.sty`; I get no error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please add instructions to make the code compilable.

Comment: `\<` is by default not defined.  Could this pose a problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  It would make it much easier to help you if you gave us a minimal working example that we could just copy and paste, then compile.  As it is, we have to add `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, and so forth, which makes it that much less likely that anyone knowing your solution will help.  Look here for help:  http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Here's a one-liner to pull a copy yourself if you're set up to SSH with GitHub: `git clone git@github.com:StevenClontz/teaching-2016-spring-math-3142.git && cd teaching-2016-spring-math-3142 && git pull origin weirdbug`

Comment: @HenriMenke `\<` is just an alias for `\langle`

Comment: `Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/StevenClontz/teaching-2016-spring-math-3142.git && cd teaching-2016-spring-math-3142 && git pull origin weirdbug` should work if you aren't set up to SSH with GitHub

Comment: FWIW, I get no errors on OS X with MacTeX 2015. As for the upper case error message, the obvious guess is that it got expanded inside an `\uppercase{…}`. But *why* that happened, I couldn't begin to guess.

Comment: Oh, wait a minute: You use the book class, which sets running page headers in uppercase. And you have chapter titles containing mathematics, and hence math delimiters. I sense the plot thickening … This observation is still far from a resolution, but it's definitely a place to be looking. For starters, try to remove all mathematics from chapter and section titles and see if the error goes away.

Comment: No the question is archived forever on this site and should be self contained, please make a small self contained example and add it inline to your question. You will have a fragile command in a chapter title that should be guarded with `\protect` but without an example can't say more.

Comment: So here's my conjecture: Even though `\(`and `\)` are declared as robust commands, perhaps some odd circumstance causes their un`\protect`ed expansion in the wrong place. In which case, `\)` might cause the failure because we're not in math mode. The odd circumstance might have something to do with the exact moment a page is being built. My advice: Replace `\(` and `\)` in the titles by `$`.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Yes, removing all mathematics from chapter/section titles fixes the error. Evidently \texorpdfstring{\(\mb R^n\)}{Rn} was the culprit.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right, of course, except that it is likely not possible to come up with a MWE in this case. If so, we can argue about whether the question belongs here at all.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen and using \texorpdfstring{$mb R^n$}{Rn} works as intended

Comment: I'll edit the original question with a MWE, now that we know what the issue actually was.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen why hard to make a MWE ? (I posted one below)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That was my guess, based on the assertion that adding one exercise triggered it. So I though it depended on the exact circumstances when the page break occured. And that would be hard to emulate in a much smaller example. But it appears I was wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although `\(` and `\)` are robust commands, it is safer to use `$` in moving arguments like chapter and section titles. This seems to be a case in which these commands were insufficiently robust.

Comment: David Carlisle's answer nails the reason for the lack of robustness, I guess. Still, using `$` signs in this context is probably fine, and it's much easier than `\protect\(`.

Comment: Correct - replacing `\(..\)` with `$..$` in my example fixes the issue.

Comment: +1 for being first (even though I'd have been quicker if not testing the example:-) yes `$` is fine and has always been available as a robust form.

Answer (score 4):

Just guessing from the error message as no example provided here

```
%\RequirePackage[2014/01/01]{latexrelease}
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{a \(x\) b}

xxx

\pagebreak
xx

\section{x}
x
\end{document}
```

One of your systems is older than 2015 and so `\(` is fragile so must be used as `\protect\(` in headings. the other system is 2015 or 2016 in which `\(` is robust.

You can emulate the older system by uncommenting the requirepackage call and see the error.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `latexrelease` package. Very handy! +1 (even though your answer competes with mine).

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen sorry. you posted while I was making the example I think. It's easier to remember packages that you wrote:-)